# Adjusting brightness in android camera api like default camera on touching the camera screen

Tags: android, camera

I am preparing a custom android camera app and wish to adjust the exposure/brightness of the camera on touch event. The default values look a bit darker than the default camera . I tried using whiteBalance(auto) function but it wont help. Was trying it using exposure like

params.setExposureCompensation(params.getExposureCompensation());

```
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                if(params.isAutoExposureLockSupported()) {
                    params.setAutoExposureLock(false);
                }
            }
```

but i am not understanding the difference between the exposure function's like ,

getExposureCompensation(), getMaxExposureCompensation(),getExposureCompensationStep()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are not actually setting the exposure.

`params.setExposureCompensation(params.getExposureCompensation());`

sets the exposure to the previous value i.e it is never changed. What you need to do is set a value between `params.getMinExposureCompensation()` and `params. getMaxExposureCompensation()`

Secondly the difference between the exposure functions is clearly explained in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html)

`getExposureCompensation`

> Gets the current exposure compensation index.
>   current exposure compensation index. The range is getMinExposureCompensation() to getMaxExposureCompensation(). 0 means exposure is not adjusted.

`getMaxExposureCompensation`

> Gets the maximum exposure compensation index.(>=0)

`getExposureCompensationStep`

> exposure compensation step. Applications can get EV by multiplying the exposure compensation index and step. Ex: if exposure compensation index is -6 and step is 0.333333333, EV is -2.

Here `EV` stands for exposure value